# how to update trained LSTM model by online data?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I'm doing a time sequence predict task, first, I trained the LSTM model by previous 50% data, I want to update the model by new data, I just simulate the online predict, Can I use one new data to update the model? the flow just like `predict update predict update` and repeat this flow,  now I'm using  the Keras, I put the new data into the `model.fit` function, Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct API for this

```
# to get indices of incorrect predictions
incorrects = np.nonzero(model.predict_class(X_test) != Y_test)

# Now train on them
newX, newY = X_test[incorrects], Y_test[incorrects]
model.fit(newX, newY)
```